# WPF Togglebutton not switching after PreviewMouseDown-Event is handled in parent control

Tags: c#, wpf

If you handle the `PreviewMouseDown` event of a `UserControl` and inside of the `UserControl` is a `ToggleButton`, it will not fire the built-in native checked-event and also not the clicked-event (highlighted blue). If you don't handle the preview-events it works fine.

I thought the preview events will not mark the event as handled, but even with

```
e.handled = false;
```

there will be no click or checked event afterwards.

How can I enable the togglebutton's click and checked event?

Code for understanding the problem:

WpfApplication1.cs

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void UserControl1_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            //working
            MessageBox.Show("Preview down");
            e.Handled = false; //this is what I tried
        }

        private void UserControl1_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            //working
            MessageBox.Show("preview up");
        }
    }
}
```

WpfApplication.Xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <local:UserControl1 PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="UserControl1_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="UserControl1_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" ></local:UserControl1>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

UserControl1.cs:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ToggleButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Not called
            MessageBox.Show("test");
        }

        private void ToggleButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //not called
            MessageBox.Show("test");
        }
    }
}
```

UserControl1.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <ToggleButton Checked="ToggleButton_Checked" Click="ToggleButton_Click"></ToggleButton>  
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: There's not really much to go off of here...

Comment: Please tell me what you need from me for further help

Comment: We need a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). More code showing exactly what you're doing, where it's going wrong, and what you've tried so far to solve it.

Comment: I added code for minimal reproduction. If I missed something please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to raise an event handler for the user control when an event from within the user control is fired. This will go up the chain and handle the even from both.

When clicking `ToggleButton`, it will fire `ToggleButton_Click` and it will trigger the event `UserControl1_PreviousMouseLeftButtonDown`.

#### WpfApplication1

```
UserControl1.ToggleButtonClick += new EventHandler(UserControl1_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown);

private void UserControl1_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Preview down");
    // Handle the event
}
```

#### UserControl1

```
public event EventHandler ToggleButtonClick;

private void ToggleButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("test");
    // Handle the event
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Unfortunatly I was not able to run your code, but still I wonder, why the preview-event is consuming the signal and not passing it on. Also does this solution provide the native toggle-behavior (blue highlighting)?

Comment: @Sceen In the cases of Parent and Child events, the Parent even take hierarchy. Check out [Event Bubbling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719644(vs.71).aspx)